# Multiple Azure AD tenants with shared callback path on IdentityServer4

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I'm implementing a Federation Gateway based on IdentityServer4, and at first I'm working on connecting to Azure AD. Everything goes fine with individual Azure tenants, but I've only gotten multiple tenants to work side by side by giving each one its own callback path. If I add multiple Azure tenants to my service without giving them individual callback paths, the authentication succeeds at Azure end, but on returning to my service I get the following error at the callback path:

```
CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte* pbCiphertext, uint cbCiphertext, Byte* pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, uint cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment<byte> ciphertext, ArraySegment<byte> additionalAuthenticatedData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(byte[] protectedData, bool allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, out UnprotectStatus status)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(byte[] protectedData, bool ignoreRevocationErrors, out bool requiresMigration, out bool wasRevoked)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, string protectedData)
IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(string protectedText, string purpose) in DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ReadPropertiesAndClearState(OpenIdConnectMessage message)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
```

The problem with individual callback paths is that each one needs to be configured separately into Azure AD. I would like to support adding new Azure tenants to my service without additional configuration inside Azure. The common endpoint at Azure works, but I need to support individual tenants as well.

How can I have multiple tenants (or external IDPs in general) share the same callback path? I found a mention about handling this with a state parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#use-a-state-parameter), but I don't know how to use one here.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Please at least explain what you tried and where things failed for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I've added more details into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, every OIDC handler needs a unique callback path. You can have a look at the Azure AD multi-tenancy feature, which only requires a single callback for all tenants.

Comment: I do have multi-tenancy enabled, and Azure seems to be just fine with redirecting all calls to the same URL. The problems occur in my service at the callback. I added some more details into my question, perhaps that clarifies the situation.